# OpenFileDialog for selecting more than 1 file with WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, controls, openfiledialog, multi-select

How can I implement an openfiledialog, which is able to do multiselecting? Do I need an extra libraray or is it also possible with the WPF-Control OpenFileDialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a property of OpenFileDialog which is MultiSelect.

So you may do this.

OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.MultiSelect = true;
dlg.Show();